# Error with novice web developer using JCarouselLite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a huge novice at web development so bear with me if this is a very trivial problem. I am trying to incorporate JCorouselLite into my website to display some content. [(Link to Developers site)](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/09/jcarousel-lite-a-jquery-plugin/?cp=15)

I am following the instructions given on the site above:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jcarousellite.js"></script>
<button class="prev"><<</button>
<div>
  <ul>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="next">>></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".default .jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".default .next",
        btnPrev: ".default .prev"
   });   
</script>
```

Which from the instructions should work. I got both jquery.js and jcarousellite.js from the site and put them both in a folder called 'js' which is in the root of my website. Can anybody see where I am going wrong? It doesn't seem to be importing the 2 scripts correctly.

Comment: if you are using firefox download the firebug addon, that will help to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the page where you're doing the Carousel in the root too? or are you down a level say '/Carousel' if so you'll need to change the src to

`src="../js/jcarousellite.js"`

**make these changes:**

```
<div class="jCarouselLite">
  <ul>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
     <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="next">>></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(".jCarouselLite").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev"
   });   
</script>
```

You were calling the jquery right. But not applying it to any div.

Comment: Yes it is, it's on the index.php page.

Comment: Is the site publicly accessible? can we see it?

Comment: Brilliant mate, thanks for taking the time to help me out, i'll accept when the timer lets me.